# mysql ColumnName AS 1, ColumnName AS 2, with WHERE, using UNION for all columns get AS 1

Tags: mysql

Have table like this

```
IdRows | UpperLevelIdRows | CategoriesName | 
-------------------------------------------------
  2    |   0              |  Transport
  4    |   2              |  Cars
  12   |   4              |  Alfa Romeo
```

Query

```
SELECT IdRows AS IdRows1, CategoriesName AS CategoriesName1 FROM categories 
WHERE UpperLevelIdRows = ?

UNION 

SELECT IdRows AS IdRows2, CategoriesName AS CategoriesName2 FROM categories 
WHERE UpperLevelIdRows = ?
```

Data for placeholders is

```
Array
(
[0] => 2
[1] => 4
)
```

So

```
 SELECT IdRows AS IdRows1 .... WHERE UpperLevelIdRows = 2
```

and

```
 SELECT IdRows AS IdRows2 .... WHERE UpperLevelIdRows = 4
```

As result expect get array like

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [IdRows1] => 4
        [CategoriesName1] => Cars
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [IdRows2] => 12
        [CategoriesName2] => Alfa Romeo
    )
```

But get array like this

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [IdRows1] => 4
        [CategoriesName1] => Cars
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [IdRows1] => 12
        [CategoriesName1] => Alfa Romeo
    )
```

Instead of `IdRows2` see `IdRows1`

If i execute only the second `SELECT IdRows AS IdRows2 ...`, then see as expected `[CategoriesName2] => Alfa Romeo`

Where is my mistake? What need to correct?

From the data i want to create select/option boxes. Like

First select box

```
echo '<select name="upper_level_id0" id="upper_level_id0" >
<option value="'.$IdRows1.'">'.$CategoriesName1.'</option>
</select>';
```

Second select box

```
echo '<select name="upper_level_id1" id="upper_level_id1" >
<option value="'.$IdRows2.'">'.$CategoriesName2.'</option>
</select>';
```

At the moment found solution using transaction. Loop through all `SELECT ...`

```
$db->beginTransaction();
foreach ( $sql_get_id_name as $k_sql => $val_sql ) {
$stmt_get_id_name = $db->prepare( $val_sql );
$stmt_get_id_name->execute( array( $data_get_id_name[$k_sql] ) );
$id_name[] = $stmt_get_id_name->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
$roll_back = $db->rollBack();
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? Is this a tree structure? I didn't understand your question

Comment: Modified text in question. Wrote what i want and what i get...

Comment: When you use union it fetches using the names from the first select. Can you explain what data you want to extract and how are you planning to use it? There are better ways to extract tree like structures from database

Comment: Modified question. Found some solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this select

```
select cp.IdRows p_id, cp.UpperLevelIdRows p_parent_id, cp.CategoriesName p_name, 
       cc.IdRows p_id, cc.UpperLevelIdRows c_parent_id, cc.CategoriesName c_name
from categories cc left join categories cp on cp.IdRows = cc.UpperLevelIdRows 
where cc.UpperLevelIdRows = 4
```

This way you will get all the sons of a parent. The first 3 columns from the result are the parent (in your row data it will be the Cars) and the second its childs (in your row data the Alfa Romeo)